# creating third table by comparing two tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

first_table ---

```
column1  column2 column3     column4
1        4512    23-05-2013
1        4512    23-05-2013
2        8465    25-06-2013
9        8745    30-08-2013
```

second_table

```
column1_2 column2_2 column3_2 column4_2
1         2         4512      23-05-2013 23:23:54
1         4         4512      23-05-2013 11:15:59
2         4         8465      25-06-2013 15:26:47
9         5         8745      30-08-2013 18:26:29
```

I want the output to be in third table as ...

```
column1 column2 column4_2
```

The first 2 tables have the count 4 and I expect the new table to have the same number of rows .
Please help . I have issues with multiple duplicate rows here .
thanks .

Comment: There is an `ON` clause missing in your `JOIN`

Comment: What's your join condition? Is it first_table.column_1 = second_table.column1_2?

Comment: Since column1 == column1_2 and column2 == column3_2 what's to stop you only using the second table?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this?  If your table is normalized use a join:

```
SELECT * from first_table JOIN second_table on first_table.column1 = second_table.column1
```

Comment: This is creating duplicate records :(

Comment: what do you mean duplicate records?  Can you post the results of the SELECT?  The only way this could produce duplicate records is if you have entered duplicate records in your first table and second table

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of duplicates, I believe that "distinct" is what you are looking for.
it seems from the example that column1 and column2_1 are the same, and column2 and column3_2 are the same.

If this is the case - you need just to query the second table as following:

```
create table third_table as 
        select distinct column1_2, column3_2, column4_2 from second_table;
```

and if you also want to make sure that this row exists in table1, then:

```
create table table3 as 
       select distinct column1_2, column3_2, column4_2  
       from second_table, first_table
       where column1=column2_1 and column2=column3_2;
```

Hope it helps